# Circular loader in react js

Tags: reactjs

I want to include a circular loading progress in react js.. [After clicking this logout button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xP1gb.jpg) After clicking logout button it has to show a spinner(font awesome icon-fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin) for some secs[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLjyZ.jpg) and button text has to change to log in.[login btn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7dGv.jpg).. 
How to do this dynamically?

Comment: Show your attempts to implement this and ask more specific questions about problems you ran into. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have something like  `loading` in your component state, you could something like this:

```
<button>{loading? <i className='fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin' /> : 'login' }</button>
```

Comment: But I want to display the icon only for few seconds.

Comment: Is there a request being sent? If so, you can set the state of the application to `loading` while you wait for the request to finish. When the authentication request is complete, you can then change the loading state and render the login string.

If there is no request being sent, you can use `setTimeout` and use whatever interval you want to change the state.

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion is to use 'semantic-ui-react' library. It contains a lot out of the box components including what you need. It has the Dimmer and Loader components that can take a boolean as a prop and change the loading and the dimming accordingly. Hope the answer would benefit you.